# How do I pattern match on two parameters in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, parameters, pattern-matching

I am quite new to Haskell, so apologies if there is any incorrect or confusing syntax. I have massively simplified what I am trying to do to make it more understandable.

To start, I have two user defined types:

```
data Foo = A String | B Int | C

type Bar = (Int, String, [Int])
```

I am trying to write a function such that:

```
myfunc :: Foo -> Bar -> Bar


--if Foo is A s,
--  increment intA
--  append s to stringA
--  return new Bar

myfunc (A s) intA stringA listA = (intA + 1) stringA++s listA 


--if Foo is B i, 
--  if listA[1]<listA[0]
--    increment intA by i
--    increment intA
--    return new Bar
--  else
--    increment intA
--    return new Bar

myfunc (B i) intA stringA (x:y:xs) = if y<x then ((intA+i)+1 stringA xs) else ((intA+1) stringA xs)



--if Foo is C,
--  increment intA
--  add listA[0], listA[1]
--  prepend to listA
--  return new Bar

myfunc (C) intA stringA (top:second:xs) = (intA + 1) stringA top+second:xs
```

So, there is a different definition of myfunc for each possible value of Foo.

I then want to access the values in the second parameter, Bar, in order to return an 'updated' Bar, updated in different ways depending on the Foo used.

I am currently encountering an error on the myfunc (B i) version of myfunc:

```
Couldn't match type ‘(Int, String, [Int])’ with ‘[Bar]’
      Expected type: [Bar]
        Actual type: Bar
```

Which I interpret as the compiler expecting a *list* of `Bar`, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Bar` value is a single tuple, not 3 separate values. Match an existing value, and create a new value for return, just as you would any other 3-tuple.

```
myfunc (A s) (intA, stringA, listA) = ((intA + 1), stringA++s, listA)
-- etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Throwing a new error: `Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘(Int, String, [Int])’
      Expected type: Bar
        Actual type: Int` - This is on the same (second) definition of myfunc, after putting what I _think_ is appropriate bracketing: `myfunc (B i) intA string (x:y:xs) = if y<x then (intA+i+1, stringA, xs) else (intA+1, stringA, xs)` - Is there anything wrong with the if statement syntax?

Comment: The same thing applies to the other cases: `myFunc` always takes *two* arguments;, with the second being a tuple. Three separate patterns do no match a tuple.